# How to correctly use urlencode

Tags: php, html, cmsmadesimple

I would like to build a url by adding the content of a php generated div.
So far the url looks like this:

```
echo '<a class="itemBook fancybox fancybox.iframe"; $url =  href="/contactforms/inspection.php?inspection=true&src=">Group Enquiry</a>';
```

and after src= I need to add the content generated by this line:

```
echo '<h3>' . $item['title'] . '<br />' . $item['location'] . '</h3>';
```

Any ideas are highly appreciated :)

Comment: The first section of code doesn't make sense.

Where are these pieces of code coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Never mix HTML and PHP !

Build your URL in PHP

```
<?php
    // building url 
    ...
    $url =  "/contactforms/inspection.php?inspection=true&src=" ;
    // send it to your front-end : i assume that an Ajax is waiting for your response
?>
```

**files are seperated**

```
<html>
    <script>
        // once you received your URL from your back-end
        var url = // value from PHP; 
        document.getElementById('linkContainer').innerHTML = "<a href='" + url + "'>My Link</a>";
    </script>
<body>
    <div id="linkContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```